# How can I find all PDFs from multiple zip files that contain the search term?

Tags: pdf, search, find, zip

Given:

- A directory with 1..n ZIP files of random names (all ending with .zip)

  - Each zip file contains 1..n PDF files of random names (all ending with .pdf)
  - All PDFs are from the same source and are to some extend comparable formatted.
  - The PDFs are no prosa text but rather invoices, inventory lists etc. (aka forms and tables; The PDFs are searchable when I open them in an PDF viewer.)
- A search term i.e. a stock item number or a invoice number

Wanted:

- A way to find/list all the PDFs that contain the given search term.
- preferably with existing linux tools.

Comment: Do the PDFs have text or images of invoices?

Comment: They have text. (The PDFs are searchable when I open them in an PDF viewer) 
added this to the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the PDF to text and then apply grep on that text:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for z in *.zip
do
  zipinfo -1 "$z" |  # Get the list of filenames in the zip file
    while IFS= read -r f
    do
      unzip -p "$z" "$f" | # Extract each PDF to standard output instead of a file
        pdftotext - - | # Then convert it to text, reading from stdin, writing to stdout
        grep -q 1234 && echo "$z -> $f" # And finally grep the text
    done
done
```