# Extract a specific pdf from a zip file with lots of pdfs

Tags: command-line, bash, pdf, zip, extract

Given:

- Name and Location of Zip-File. Example: collectionOfPdfFiles2017.zip

  - Zip File is a collection of PDFs without folder structure
- Name of PDF File in Zip-File. Example: someFileFrom2017.pdf

Wanted:

- Console way of extracting the named PDF from the given zip file
- The file should be unmodified.

  - Basically the extracted file should be in the same condition as I would get it by extracting the whole archive and copying the wanted file by hand.
- Ideally into a destination folder. But that is luxury.

How do I do this? 
Currently I have a script that will search for strings in PDF files insides ZIPs and prints out the name of the zip and the pdf inside it. 
I'll post this for good messure:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "Hi I'll find text in pdf files that are stored inside zip files."
    echo ""
    echo "Enter search string:"
    read searchString

    echo "Ok. I'll search all zip files for content with this text..."

    for z in *.zip
    do
    zipinfo -1 "$z" |  # Get the list of filenames in the zip file
        while IFS= read -r f
        do
        unzip -p "$z" "$f" | # Extract each PDF to standard output instead of a file
            pdftotext - - | # Then convert it to text, reading from stdin, writing to stdout
            grep -q $searchString && echo "$z -> $f" # And finally grep the text
        done
    done
```

This script was created thanks to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963824/how-can-i-find-all-pdfs-from-multiple-zip-files-that-contain-the-search-term).

Comment: So what is wrong with this script?

Comment: Your script and your question seems to be conflicting.. You want to find and extract a pdf that contains specific text? So its not related to filename of pdf? Please review your question

Comment: The script I posted above is one that I use to find which zip-files contain pdf files that I need. It is indeed not an solution to my problem. But it provides the skeleton for the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unzip specific file from zip archive

```
unzip -j "myarchive.zip" "in/archive/file.pdf" -d "/destination/path/"
```

In your script

```
# Set a destination path
dest="/path/to/unzip/to"
# dump pdf to temp text file
tempfile=$(mktemp)
# unzip the file to stdOut and convert it to text
unzip -p "$z" "$f" | pdftotext - $tempfile
if grep -q $searchString $tempfile; then
    unzip -j "$z" "$f" -d "$dest"
    # some text output
    echo "$z -> $f"
fi
rm $tempfile
```

Comment: Hmm... I can not get it running. It says that grep expects a unary operator.

Comment: Oops, answer edited

Comment: nearly correct. It must be "| pdftotext - $tempfile" The "-" was missing.

Comment: Another problem was for me, that I replaced $dest directly with a fixed folder. In this case I needed to remove the quotes. (Not "~/output/dir" but ~/output/dir).